# Why does "the open" have the "the"?

Tags: meaning, articles

I want to know why "open" has a "the"?

Because it refers to "**any** wide or unobstructed space or expanse" and it isn't specific?.

> *to cause to remain **in the open***

Reference: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leave-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, *in the open* is a common idiomatic phrase.  Such phrases often are fixed and don't follow the state of the surrounding sentence.

Second, this thinking here:

> Because it refers to "any wide or unobstructed space or expanse"

is wrong.  There is only *one* "open" - you can apply this word to describe any *specific* wide or unobstructed space or expanse.

By using the definite article, the speaker is expecting you to know *which "unobstructed space or expanse"* already, or is assuming you know which due to him/her thinking you are seeing what he/she sees.

But again it is possible to use the phrase *in the open* abstractly to mean "where anyone can see you" or similar.

Also you can make this simple with this heuristic - it would be rare to see the the term *in an / any open* without it being *in an / any open X*